Solana program interaction (CPI into another program) transactions silently dropped
I've been going crazy for the past couple of days trying to understand the issue (still a noob and learning solana programs, rust, runtime, ...etc - I come from eth):
I have created a simple program that CPIs into raydium (literally one instruction). I am using same accounts you would use to directly interact with raydium sdk from typescript and same inputs. I have built and deployed program via anchor to mainnet after extensively testing on localnet. I am running two scripts: the first directly interacts with raydium trying to swap a token, the other sends the same instruction to my program to swap the same token using same inputs and accounts.
Using same rpc, same priority fee, ...etc direct interaction with raydium would land much much more txs than interacting with my program. The comparison isn't even close! Only if I increase priority (multiply it by like a 100) for my program interaction I would start getting somewhere close results (direct raydium interaction would still land more tho). Difference in compute limit is also negligible.
Any clue what could be the issue? Do cargo dependencies version play any role?

Please provide some more concrete information about how you send the transaction to directly, how you send it to your program, and the logic in your program. With the information as it is, it's extremely hard to debug!
